# Finding the burial place of British service members killed in WW2

Tags: united-kingdom, world-war-2, grave-marker

I am trying to find out where my granddad is buried. He was a Corporal with the Lancashire Fusiliers serving in the second World War.

Comment: Hi, welcome to genealogy.SE. I am sorry to say, but your questions doesn't contain much information to help you. What do you know (name, date of death, records)?

Comment: If you are thinking about including the name of your grandfather, please be aware that ["You must not include here in any circumstances information (including name, date and place of birth or any other details) that would allow identification of any living (or possibly) living individual by somebody reading this site. In practice, this means details about anyone born in the last 100 years, whether they are believed to be deceased or not, and whether or not they have given their permission."](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @PolyGeo - I don't understand the application of the sentence you have pasted in to these circumstances. They refer to "living (or possibly living)" individuals. It appears to me that there is no doubt about the matter and the name will appear on the Commonwealth War Graves Commission website. Certainly, if further details are provided than appear on the CWGC site that might allow identification of other family members, then that ought not to happen.

Comment: @AdrianB38 It is a policy I struggle with because it makes "how to ask" some questions harder than would be the case in its absence.  The grandfather in question here was fighting in World War 2 so even if he died in 1939 may have only been born in 1920.  If the asker can confirm that he was born in 1914 or earlier then full disclosure of such details will not be a problem.  Alternatively, if the asker can include an official URL (e.g. from Commonwealth War Graves Commission website) that demonstrates the grandfather is deceased that will be fine too.  I know it's Catch 22.

Comment: @PolyGeo - I don't have a problem with the policy proper. It's the "in practice" bit that doesn't help because it *expands* the coverage. The original poster (OP) is clear that their GF died but the policy's "in practice" tells us to disregard their opinion. The "in practice" bit is not helpful (because, as we both agree, it makes the question harder to phrase) and disrespectful to the OP.

Comment: @AdrianB38 you have valid concerns -- can we discuss them in [Meta](http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1900/how-much-detail-should-be-included-in-questions-about-ww1-and-ww2-service-member)?

Answer (score 5):

A search of the [Commonwealth War Graves Commission](http://www.cwgc.org/find-war-dead.aspx?cpage=1) grave locator for service members from WW2 who served with the Lancashire Fusiliers with a rank of Corporal yields 103 records.  If your granddad is in the database, having his military service number would help you distinguish his entry from another service member with the same name.

Do you have any records in your family that say what battalion he might have served with?  Another thing you could try is to search for general information about the Lancashire Fusiliers during WW2, and then look for casualty lists for that battalion.

Another option is to contact [The Fusilier Museum](http://www.fusiliermuseum.com/family-history) in Bury for research help.  Their site says:

> Please note there is a £25 charge for this service.

According to their site, the list of information they have includes:

> - Casualty lists for the Crimean War, Indian Mutiny, Sudanese War, Boer War, WWI, WWII
> - All soldiers killed in action (from any regiment)
> - All campaigns and burial sites of all WWI and WWII soldiers of the regiment